# overriding the package specified in default list from cli

Tags: python-3.x, config, fb-hydra

I am trying to override the package in default list in a hierarchical configuration structure. As a simplified example:

I have `conf/base.yaml`

```
defaults:
  - _self_
  - env@_here_: env1
a: 1
b: 2
```

`conf/env/env1.yaml`

```
c: 5
d: 6
```

and `conf/env/env2.yaml`

```
c: 7
d: 8
```

When running `my_app.py`

```
import hydra
import omegaconf

@hydra.main(config_path="conf", config_name="base")
def my_app(cfg: omegaconf.DictConf) -> None:
    print(omegaconf.OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg))

my_app()
```

I want to override `env@_here_` from `env1` to `env2` using the CLI or any other method. I have gone through Hydra documentation a few times, but couldn't find how to do this.

Comment: I believe there is a bug here. It should be possible to type `python my_app.py env@_global_=env2` at the command line, but currently this does not work. I've filed a bug report [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1803).

Comment: I followed the issue and the PR linked to it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current hydra release (Hydra 1.1.1) you can use:

```
python my_app.py env=env2
```

Due to a recent [breaking change](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/pull/1791) to improve consistency of Hydra's API, it will soon be necessary to do this:

```
python my_app.py env@_global_=env2
```

This breaking change will probably be a part of Hydra 1.1.2 or 1.2.0.

Side note:
There are a few different ways to achieve the same result as you have in your example above.
Your options include:

- Using `- env@_here_: env1` in `base.yaml`, which is what you did above.
- Using `- env@_global_: env1` in `base.yaml`
- Using `- env: env1` in `base.yaml` and adding a `_global_` [package header](https://hydra.cc/docs/upgrades/0.11_to_1.0/adding_a_package_directive) to `env1.yaml` and `env2.yaml`

`conf/env/env1.yaml`:

```yaml
# @package _global_
c: 5
d: 6
```

`conf/env/env2.yaml`:

```yaml
# @package _global_
c: 7
d: 8
```

The keyword `_global_` refers to the top-level package in the output config produced by Hydra.
You can read more [here](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/advanced/overriding_packages/#default-list-package-keywords) about the `_global_` and `_here_` keywords.